# Verbose logging during testing but terse logging in the released application

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging

I'm making a Maven-based java library which the logging used is this:

```
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    private static final Logger LOG 
        = Logger.getLogger(MyLibraryClass.class.getName())
```

I have coded so many log in this library, that is very useful in debugging the flow of the library, specially during JUnit tests, however this app I created, I don't want it to show the logs to a client application (an application that will use this library). Since it is too verbose.

How do I control which gets logged into a client application's log view. Logs like `INFO level` from the library does not necessarily show up in the client/sample app?

Here is my ultimate goal:

- To have a log as verbose as possible when running Unit test in the
  library project
- But not show these "verbose" logs to the client application, without the need for the client application to deliberately configure/suppress the logs from the library

> **Client library** - is the project that is used by a Java application; which is the project I am working on. Which generates logs that should not be displayed in the client application.
>
> **Client application** - is the project/application that uses the Java
> library

Comment: If you are using log4j, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231773/specifying-a-custom-log4j-properties-file-for-all-of-junit-tests-run-from-eclips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client-App needs his own tests. I dont understand why the Client-lib shouldnt be released if there are problems in the Client-App anyway (just a dead-end-situation).

I see two maven-projects.

- The Library (with Library-Tests)
- The Client-App (with Client-App-Tests) with a dependency to the Library

So you have for the Library a noop-config-file in

```
/src/test/java/resources/logging.properties
```

and in the Client-App a noop-config-file in

```
/src/main/java/resources/logging.properties
```

Such a noop-config looks like this:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
level= SEVERE
```

Comment: That's the content of a log4j.properties file not of a logging.properties

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for this

```
 LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure log level in log4j.properties or log4j.xml

Use separate log4j.properties for your Unit test.

In maven put a log4j.properties  or log4j.xml file into src/test/resources

Or use CLI properties when running junit

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=<path to properties file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your log messages too high a priority. All INFO, WARN and ERROR messages should be messages you would expect your users to see. If a message is useful only to developers,  it should be DEBUG or TRACE. Then configure your logging lubrary to display only INFO, WARN and ERROR messages.