# Is there a simple way to log everything in Java?

Tags: java, logging

In teaching myself about Java errors and warnings, I have been exploring the documentation for  `java.util.logging.Logger`. It seems as if everything within the `Logger` class is geared toward logging specific items--which makes sense from a practical persepctive.

However, I would like to be able to log *everything* that can be logged. It fits my learning style to look at everything that can be logged for a working program, then break things to see how the logfile changes. From there, it's easier for me to understand how to control what does and doesn't get logged.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954282/logging-with-a-java-library) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343600/implementing-logging-in-a-java-application) with which I'm going to be starting, but I'm wondering if there are other resources that'd help me implement a "log everything" solution to increase my understanding of the class?

Comment: Nothing gets logged unless someone or something tells it to.

Comment: In general you should set the logging level to DEBUG to see everything that can be logged in the classes you are working with.

Comment: I recommend you change your learning style. That's the worst I've heard yet.

Comment: You should use a debugger and go step by step in it to see where your program is going.

Answer (score 0):

The logging classes will add messages to one or more appenders.  You have to give it messages - it seems you're asking how you can log everything so I don't have to give a message to log.  This isn't what loggers do.  I think what you want is a debugger, and then step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing logs on its own. 
Given that you have two options:

1. **Use a debugger instead**. It matches more with your requirements. Step through the code and inspect variables on the fly. To use debugger, you can use any standard IDE like IntelliJ Idea or Eclipse.
2. **Use AOP** : Define an aspect which keeps logging all method parameters and return types. You could use Spring AOP for that

If you are a beginner, I would recommend option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am with the two other guys, but if you wanna see errors, you could use Exceptions with try-catch blocks like this:

```
    try
    {
       //enter your code here
       Test f = new Test();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```